# Wrap a div around every 2 elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some HTML like this:

```
<span>Header Here</span>
<span>Content Here</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
<span>Some Other Content Here</span>
```

As you can see the HTML isn't really formatted in a very accessible way, and unfortunately I can't change the output, what I need to do is wrap every 2 spans with a div so the output becomes this:

```
<div class="row">
    <span>Header Here</span>
    <span>Content Here</span>
</div>
<div class="row offsetRow">
    <span>Another Header</span>
    <span>Some Other Content Here</span>
</div>
```

The offsetRow class will repeat every other row.

Is this even possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.wrapAll()` like

```js
var $els = $('span');
for (var i = 0; i < $els.length; i += 2) {
  $els.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll('<div class="row ' + (i > 0 && i % 2 == 0 && i % 4 != 0 ? 'offsetRow' : '') + '"></div>')
}
```

```css
.row {
  color: grey
}
.offsetRow {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Header Here</span>
<span>Content Here</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
<span>Another Header</span>
```

Comment: It worked, but it didn't need the wrapAll, just a wrap, other than that worked perfectly! Thanks